# Class 'Task' has no 'objects' member

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

#I don't know where have I made a mistake, there is a error says Class 'Task' has no 'objects' member

```
'''
 views.py
 
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from .models import *

 # Create your views here.

 def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    context = {'tasks':tasks}
    return render(request,'task/list.html',context)
'''


'''
 models.py
 from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.
 class Task(models.Model):

     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     complete =models.BooleanField(default=False)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.title


'''

'''
list.html

<h3>To Do</h3>

{%for first in task %}
   <div>
       <p>{{first}}</p>
   </div>    

{% endfor %}

'''
```

One more thing which is the database SQL lite inbuilt, I have created task but it does not shows below
ex: It should be like

```
Task
playing   
Dancing
```

It says

```
Task
Task Object(2)   
Task Object(1)
```

Comment: You need to indent the `__str__` method, so the `__str__` method should be a member of the `Task` class.

Comment: Can you provide the result when you `print(Task.__mro__)` in the view (*before* the `.objects`)?

Comment: its simply print To Do

Comment: I have tried as you said below but It's giving an OperationalError when I open the task

Answer (score 0):

Test this code in views.py :

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from . import models

 def index(request):
    tasks = models.Task.objects.all()
    context = {'tasks':tasks}
    return render(request,'task/list.html',context)
```